# PHP __callStatic & invalid method name characters

Tags: php, static-methods, magic-methods

Quick question regarding `__callStatic()` in PHP;

```
class Test{
    public static function __callStatic($method, $arguments){
        echo $method . PHP_EOL;
    }
    public function __call($method, $arguments){
        echo $method . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

$test->foo();
$test->{'hello-world'}();

Test::bar();
Test::{'goodbye-universe'}();
```

Expected output:

```
foo
hello-world
bar
goodbye-universe
```

Actual output:

```
foo
hello-world
bar
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in - on line 18
```

Is this syntax not permissible, nor functionality achievable with `__callStatic()`?

*Note*: Trying to get away with **no** temporary variables. The following will work:

```
$goodbyeUniverse = 'goodbye-universe';
Test::$goodbyeUniverse();
```

But I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in PHP 5.4

> `04 Aug 2011, PHP 5.4.0 Alpha 3`
>   `- Added features:`
>    `. Short array syntax, see UPGRADING guide for full details`
>      `(rsky0711 at gmail . com, sebastian.deutsch at 9elements . com, Pierre)`
>    `. Binary numbers format (0b001010). (Jonah dot Harris at gmail dot com)`
>    **`. Support for Class::{expr}() syntax (Pierrick)`**

https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/tags/php_5_4_0RC8/NEWS

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the PHP parser can handle that currently. I cannot prove it just now, but I think it's a similar issue like the array-dereferencing-issue after function calls (`callme()['arraykey']`).

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Gehrig - That's what I'm starting to think, unfortunately. I've tried a plethora of different string parsing tricks, but it all comes back to an unexpected brace `{` that PHP doesn't like. This is terribly unfortunate, because now I have to resort to a singleton to implement this functionality without an instance in scope, via `__call()`.

Answer (score 1):

you could invoke a static function via [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)().

Comment: Thanks @Raffael1984 - Yea, that is an option, albeit a bit dirtier than I was hoping for, not to mention now I have method look-ups occurring, once for the `call_user_func()` and one for `__callStatic()`. Only viable option so far though.